# Unique constraint for new values only

Tags: mysql-5.5, index

I have a large table with a column that contains duplicates.

I want to add a `unique` constraint on this column for future entries only (not the old data).

Is this possible?

Comment: You first have to delete duplicates, then add the `UNIQUE` constraint.

Comment: @ypercube thk for you reply but it's Impossible for business reasons ! no other solution ? like in oracle with option NOVALIDATE ?

Comment: You would need to create the index anyway which will fail.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any way as for future inserts you will need to have the index. Maybe consider adding another column to your table ensuring the uniqueness. This could be filled with a trigger function on new inserts.

Comment: Nice solution! +1!

Comment: More like a crude hack ;) Really depends on data it could be a working workaround, nothing more. It's not solving the issue of bad (read: not unique) data inside the uniqueness needed column.

Comment: Of course - but AFAICS, it provides the only resolution to the OP's question - short of a complete redesign, which the OP appears to wish to avoid.